# Trying to add a column to SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, create-table, alter-table

I am getting `incorrect syntax` errors with the following statement (SQL Server 2017)

```
USE ToDo
GO

ALTER TABLE tasks ADD COLUMN completed TINYINT(1);
```

> Started executing query at Line 1
> Commands completed successfully.
> 20:31:38Started executing query at Line 3

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COLUMN'.

A very similar syntax was used to remove a column that worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

This code would run in MySQL - but not on SQL Server. Consider:

```
alter table tasks add completed tinyint;
```

Rationale:

- `alter table` does not support `column` in SQL Server; just remove that keyword
- the `tinyint` datatype does not take a length

Comment: Tried that same error. Anyway it is a boolean value I am holding so I only want a single digit for 0 or 1

Comment: Then you can consider using the `BIT` type.

Comment: @PrestonDocks: this codes runs in SQL Server, as you can see [in this DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d2a0311d3b33accb579a9315ef145e1d).

Comment: Thank you. I had to remove `column` which is required for removing a column. I am just getting used to MSSQL and it seems a bit inconsistent. Anyway it works, thank you.